# Error when I add credit card for billing (OR-CCSEH-21) Solved

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-play-services

I got error today when I trying to add my credit card that say:

`Your requset failed. Use a diffrent payment method or contact us.`

Code error: `OR-CCSEH-21`

- My alert is clean
- I tried all my credit cards
- I tried to change region
- I tried to change my WIFI

It was working previously.
Please I need to solve this quickly because I want to set a plan in firestore.

[image: Alert]

[image: OR-CCSEH-21]

Comment: The error is clear, you need to contact Google Cloud Support to resolve this issue.

Comment: I can't find a way to contact them

Comment: Google is your friend: https://cloud.google.com/support-hub

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the payment method that you're using and not an issue with using Google Cloud. Similar [threads](https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/179396217/or-ccseh-21?hl=en) has been posted on Google Play Community. If you're adding a payment method on Google Cloud Platform, it's best to reach out to their [support channel](https://cloud.google.com/support).

Answer (score 0):

The code provided is already present in the official documentation for integrating Google Pay. I encountered a similar issue while testing in the sandbox environment, and I used the original card details for testing purposes. The only additional information required is the card number and expiration date, which you can provide accurately. For testing purposes, you can enter an incorrect CVV and verify the environment as well.

Update the environment accordingly:-
**new google.payments.api.PaymentsClient({environment: 'TEST'});**

HTML Code:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script async
  src="https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js"
  onload="onGooglePayLoaded()"></script>
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
const baseRequest = {
  apiVersion: 2,
  apiVersionMinor: 0
};
const allowedCardNetworks = ["AMEX", "DISCOVER", "INTERAC", "JCB", "MASTERCARD", "VISA"];
const allowedCardAuthMethods = ["PAN_ONLY", "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"];
const tokenizationSpecification = {
  type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
  parameters: {
    'gateway': 'example',
    'gatewayMerchantId': 'exampleGatewayMerchantId'
  }
};


const baseCardPaymentMethod = {
  type: 'CARD',
  parameters: {
    allowedAuthMethods: allowedCardAuthMethods,
    allowedCardNetworks: allowedCardNetworks
  }
};

const cardPaymentMethod = Object.assign(
  {},
  baseCardPaymentMethod,
  {
    tokenizationSpecification: tokenizationSpecification
  }
);

let paymentsClient = null;

function getGoogleIsReadyToPayRequest() {
  return Object.assign(
      {},
      baseRequest,
      {
        allowedPaymentMethods: [baseCardPaymentMethod]
      }
  );
}

function getGooglePaymentDataRequest() {
  const paymentDataRequest = Object.assign({}, baseRequest);
  paymentDataRequest.allowedPaymentMethods = [cardPaymentMethod];
  paymentDataRequest.transactionInfo = getGoogleTransactionInfo();
  paymentDataRequest.merchantInfo = {
    merchantName: 'Example Merchant'
  };
  return paymentDataRequest;
}

function getGooglePaymentsClient() {
  if ( paymentsClient === null ) {
    paymentsClient = new google.payments.api.PaymentsClient({environment: 'TEST'});
  }
  return paymentsClient;
}

function onGooglePayLoaded() {
  const paymentsClient = getGooglePaymentsClient();
  paymentsClient.isReadyToPay(getGoogleIsReadyToPayRequest())
      .then(function(response) {
        if (response.result) {
          addGooglePayButton();
          // prefetchGooglePaymentData();
        }
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
      });
}

function addGooglePayButton() {
  const paymentsClient = getGooglePaymentsClient();
  const button =
      paymentsClient.createButton({onClick: onGooglePaymentButtonClicked});
  document.getElementById('container').appendChild(button);
}

function getGoogleTransactionInfo() {
  return {
    countryCode: 'US',
    currencyCode: 'USD',
    totalPriceStatus: 'FINAL',
    // set to cart total
    totalPrice: '1.00'
  };
}

function prefetchGooglePaymentData() {
  const paymentDataRequest = getGooglePaymentDataRequest();
  paymentDataRequest.transactionInfo = {
    totalPriceStatus: 'NOT_CURRENTLY_KNOWN',
    currencyCode: 'USD'
  };
  const paymentsClient = getGooglePaymentsClient();
  paymentsClient.prefetchPaymentData(paymentDataRequest);
}

function onGooglePaymentButtonClicked() {
  const paymentDataRequest = getGooglePaymentDataRequest();
  paymentDataRequest.transactionInfo = getGoogleTransactionInfo();

  const paymentsClient = getGooglePaymentsClient();
  paymentsClient.loadPaymentData(paymentDataRequest)
      .then(function(paymentData) {
        // handle the response
        processPayment(paymentData);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        // show error in developer console for debugging
        console.error(err);
      });
}

function processPayment(paymentData) {
  
    console.log(paymentData);
  paymentToken = paymentData.paymentMethodData.tokenizationData.token;
}
```